# Run docker container on AWS EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, port, docker-container

In my EC2 instance, I am running a docker container. I can ssh to the docker container using the following command

```
sudo docker exec -it jt /bin/bash
```

I can see that docker is running when I run the command `sudo docker ps`
And I get the following output

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
16d5b196693d        image_name   "tini -g -- /bin/bash"   36 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       8888/tcp, 9443/tcp   jt
```

But when I open the public IP Address with the port, `http:PublicIPAddress:8888`, the page doesn't load.

I have already created the inbound rules for 8888. 9443 but it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: What is the command you used to run the docker image?

Answer (score -1):

Can you cross check the ports specified in YML file.